# How do I use an Entity Reference List view display with a webform entity select/radio field?

Tags: views, entities, webforms

I'm using Drupal 8, and have a webform for users to designate a proxy at meetings. The webform has a field for meeting date, and I want to restrict that to scheduled meeting dates.

I already have a `content type` for meeting announcements, so I added a `view` with format `Entity reference list`, with one field for `Meeting date`. In the preview, I get the result I want: a list of datetimes for future meetings. I then added an `entity select field` in my webform, and chose the entity that I created. But the form shows the title of the node (e.g, "Announcement: Meeting on June 2, 2018"). How can I get just the date (e.g., "June 2, 2018") in the webform?

Comment: You're saying that you see "June 2, 2018" in your view preview, but not in the webform? Did you do anything in the Webform UI to tell it to use your view? I assume "Announcement: Meeting on June 2, 2018" is a title of a node? Also is this D7 or D8?

Comment: Yes, the title of the node (I had a typo "note" instead of node; now corrected). Yes to your other questions. In the webform ui, I added an entity select field, and chose the view that I had created. It's D8 (added that to my post as well; sorry for forgetting that.)

Comment: This sounds like a bug with the module, you should follow up in the drupal issue queue. It sounds like this issue: [Rewritten view output is not used for "Entity Select" field](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2890618)